# Xcode 6 - Issue with displaying the game after Xcode update (spriteKit)

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, xcode6

I have done a simple `spriteKit game` that was created in `Xcode 5.1.1`. Everything worked and displayed great. Today I updated to `Xcode 6.0 (6.0.1)` but my application after "Build and Run" in Simulator and also in iPhone is now "broken". Textures are not correct and stretched out. The game is now totally unusable and graphically disastrous.

Does anyone know what is the problem and what has happened?

Thank you in advance for your advice.

EDIT:

```
// Configure the view.
SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
skView.showsFPS = NO;
skView.showsNodeCount = NO; // Turn off for the AppStore!

// Create and configure the scene.
SKScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:CGSizeMake(skView.frame.size.width, skView.frame.size.height)];
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

// Present the scene.
[skView presentScene:scene];
```

Comment: xcode5.1 contain a bug where SKview retrun wrong height and width it is fixed in xcode6.0 and above please check the size of your skview you would get right width and right.

Comment: @dragoneye Thank you! I fixed it, but now I have black thin areas on the sides (like app for iPhone 4 on iPhone 5). What have I missed? I edited the question and added some code.

Comment: I solved it. You added correct size of images for LaunchImage and now it works. Thank you again for help.